# pathon scrapy FormRequest formdata which assigned through on the page# click, and

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

Sending a formdata like formdata={__EVENTTARGET: ctl00$cph1$grdRfqSearch, __EVENTARGUMENT: Page$4}, this assign through on event from page href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cph1$grdRfqSearch','Page$4')"

I can't directly assign like above since it triggers from page# click(javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cph1$grdRfqSearch','Page$3')); how to pass same value in FormRequest